# how can i apply associative array technique to a form in php?

Tags: php

I am working a form where i have to adopt associative array technique. the user will select a product size and enter the corresponding stock. once post the corresponding stock will be associated to the corresponding size value.
Here is the form:

```
   <form action="test1.php" method="post">
    <p>Choose a Size or more and enter its Stock</p>
    Size :<select name="articleSize[]" id="articleSize[]">
        <option value="">Select a size</option>
        <option value="xl">XL</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="unique">Unique</option>
        <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
    </select>
    Stock : <input type="text" name="articleStock[]" id="articleStock[]" size="8" id="stock" value="">

    <p>Choose a Size or more and enter its Stock (optional)</p>
    Size :<select name="articleSize[]" id="articleSize[]">
        <option value="">Select a size</option>
        <option value="xl">XL</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
        <option value="unique">Unique</option>
        <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
    </select>
    Stock : <input type="text" name="articleStock[]" id="articleStock[]" size="8" id="stock" value="">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </p>
    </form>
```

I have tried myself based on what i know and here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$arrSize = $_POST['articleSize'];
$arrStock = $_POST['articleStock'];

foreach ($arrSize as $size_key => $sizeValue) {
    foreach ($arrStock as $stock_Key => $stockVal) {
        if ($size_key == $stock_Key) {
            $newArray[$sizeValue] = $stockVal;
        }
    }

 }
 if (count($newArray) >=1) { 
     foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
        echo "Size is ".$key. " and stock is ".$value;
     }
  }

}
```

My code is working as excepted but is't there better way to do it?

The result shoud be like.

```
$stock_size = array(the size=> its corresponding stock);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate inner `foreach` like this:

```
foreach ($arrSize as $size_key => $sizeValue) {
    if (!empty($arrStock[$size_key])) {
        $newArray[$sizeValue] = $arrStock[$size_key];
    }
}
```

If there's a need to count `0` values too you can:

```
foreach ($arrSize as $size_key => $sizeValue) {
    if (!empty($arrStock[$size_key]) && (int)$arrStock[$size_key] >=0 ) {
        $newArray[$sizeValue] = $arrStock[$size_key];
    }
}
```

And if you're sure that all values have pairs:

```
foreach ($arrSize as $size_key => $sizeValue) {
    $newArray[$sizeValue] = $arrStock[$size_key];
}
```

which is the same as

```
$newArray = array_combine($arrSize, $arrStock);
```

**Update** with function:

```
function makePairs($arrSize, $arrStock)
{
    $newArray = [];

    foreach ($arrSize as $size_key => $sizeValue) {
        if (!empty($arrStock[$size_key])) {
            $newArray[$sizeValue] = $arrStock[$size_key];
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}

// Call like
print_r(makePairs($_POST['articleSize'], $_POST['articleStock']));
```

Comment: thanks for your advise...it working like i wanted...i did not want to return an array with empty values included..

Comment: how can i translate the above as a function ? because the return value as to be a function?

Comment: Please ask another question, I don't understand what it means `translate as a function`.

Comment: i was saying that how can i successfully take above code and make it as a function. so the function will return false if no value has been enter or return array if values has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_combine` which will create `key-value` pair array

```
$arrSize = $_POST['articleSize'];
$arrStock = $_POST['articleStock'];

$stock_size = array_combine ( $arrSize ,$arrStock );
```